# How to change list column Display Name in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: list, sharepoint, field, spservices

I have Custom List with default "Title" column.

How can I change it's Display Name to something like "Project" with JS?

*SPServices* library has method *UpdateList* with *updateFields* parameter.

In official documentation it's just 
    [sets up a default value for field](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateList&referringTitle=Lists).

How can I change Display Name with it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, if anyone is interested

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Your List Name');
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle('Title');
field.set_title('new title');
field.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { alert('success'); });
```